# I have been in charge of a non-registered "organisation", should I put this on my CV/linked in?

Tags: resume, work-experience, linkedin

In 2015 I started an esports team, that later bridged into me doing a lot of web-development, marketing, graphic design and some other minor work. I never registered the team as an organisation, as we never made any money, and never had the intention to do so. Technically, I still "work" for this organisation, so that would mean that my CV/linked in would say "current job". Would this look bad to companies I apply for a job with?

I am wondering if I should put that on my CV/linked in? It has given me a lot of experience, and I did not work alone, meaning that I have people to put as references. My main concern is that they might not contact me further due to it saying "current job".

Comment: The organisation might never have been official but is it traceable? What happens if you google the name? Because any prospective employer will check that long before they worry about it being "official"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already having a position as opposed to being unemployed actually makes you a more desirable candidate. As far as putting not-for-profit  work on your resume, if the work you do is relevant to the field, there is no reason not to put it there and no one will think less of the experience you gained from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you think I should put "2015-current" as the timeframe, or should I do "2015-2018"?

Comment: I'd put the months as part of the timeframe too. If you are still working on it, it will be current otherwise the month you stopped doing work. If you are taking a break and think you will go back  to do some more you can still say current.

Comment: "If the work you do is relevant to the field", Yes! If its revelant , even if it's not payed, a stage etc. The amount of student sending CV with all the  "grocery and casier job" instead of every stage and revelant activity is incredible. It's a must include. Waiting for interview to talk about the "2 years work in the field in short mission" is not a good idea. Because without those informations you may fail the screening and never get into interview.

Answer (score 1):

**Resumes are sales tools.** You're selling yourself by showing off your skills, accomplishments, and experience. If the time you've spent on this project contributes to skills or experience that's relevant to the jobs you're going after, then you should **absolutely** include it on your resume.

Of course, **resumes have to be accurate.** You don't want to pass this organization off as a legitimate company if it isn't, which is why stuff like this is sometimes listed in a "personal projects" or "other relevant experience" section, separate from your actual employment history. This way, you can show off what you've accomplished without causing confusion.

Think of it this way: Are you applying for jobs in web development, marketing, and graphic design? If yes, then recruiters will care about those aspects of this project. I'm assuming you're not applying for jobs where you'd be responsible for registering and administrating the legal aspects of a company's status - so, people will generally not care about how (or if) you did that for a side project like this.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** If it pays taxable money, it's a job.

I'm also a server admin and (effectively) community manager for a small mil-sim team. I don't make any money out of it but I put it on my CV under *Personal Projects* at the end, because I have done relevant technical work that would interest potential employers.

Now, you're making money out of this, so it is *by default* a job. I'd think paying taxes on that income would be most of your obligations to the country you're in. For example in the UK you don't have to start a business to sell on eBay, but you still have to report that income.

And if you ever get any trouble for not registering the organization, it would come from the tax agency, not your LinkedIn contacts.